# angularjs testing with jasmine - $httpBackend not giving me the right behavior

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is my Controller:

```
rcCtrls.controller('LoginController', [
'$scope', 
'AuthService',
function($scope, AuthService)
{
    console.log('LoginController');
    $scope.credantials = {
            email:      '',
            password:   '',
            remember:   false
    }
    $scope.login = function(credantials)
    {
        console.log('before login');
        AuthService.login(credantials.email, credantials.password, credantials.remember || false).success(function(response) {
            console.log('login successful');
            console.log(response);
            location.reload();
        }).error(function() {
            console.log('failed to login');
        });
    };
}]);
```

This is my AuthService:

```
rcServices.factory('AuthService', [
'$http',
function($http) 
{ 
    return {
        login: function(email, password, remember) {
            console.log('Auth Service Login');
            return $http.post('/auth/login', {email: email, password: password, remember: remember});
        },
        logout: function() {
            return $http.post('/auth/logout');
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is my spec:

```
describe('Controller: LoginController', function() {
    // We initiate the app moudle mock
    beforeEach(module('app')); // alias for angular.mock.module('app')

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, AuthService, $httpBackend){
        this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('LoginController', {
            $scope: this.scope,
            AuthService: AuthService
        });
    }));

    describe("checking credantials at the begining", function() {
        it("should be initiated", function() {
            expect(this.scope.credantials).toEqual({ email: '', password: '', remember: false });
        });
    });

    describe("successfully logged in", function() {
        it("should redirect to home", function() {
            this.scope.credantials = { email: 'test@mail.com', password: '123', remember: false };
            this.$httpBackend.expectPOST('/auth/login', this.scope.credantials).respond(200, {test: 'test'});
            this.scope.login(this.scope.credantials);
            console.log(this);
            this.$httpBackend.flush();
            expect(this.scope).toBeDefined();
        });
    });

});
```

It seems as if the $httpBackend doesn't do what it is suppose to do.

I indeed get all the console logs up until the moment where my Service uses $http post request, and there it stops.

FYI, my controller is working properly on the app itself! The post is happening and the response is returning properly.

However the test just doesn't...

I'm getting and error:
`Error: No pending request to flush !`
Commenting it doesn't help.

EDIT:

**The issue was my angular-mock.js version.... how sad.**

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an afterEach block somewhere else in your app that calls $httpBackend.flush?

Comment: Positive. This is as plain as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service you call:

```
        location.reload();
```

This could be messing with jasmine and causing unpredictable behavior. What does this call do, do you need it, and what happens to your tests if you just comment that out?

If you **really** need to make that call, you should use AngularJS built in $location service and mock it so that you keep the behavior but not break jasmine in the process.

===========

Update:

Additionally, it's a little odd that you're using this.httpBackend, when normally you'd totally overwrite the reference - not storing it as an attribute of this but a variable global to your tests. I am suspicious that somewhere else in your app you have called flush already and the reference isn't being reset properly. Do you have any other tests calling flush, anywhere?

http://plnkr.co/edit/jBewavvO1n8NBa6WGFja

I made working tests in this plunkr, which pass with your code as it is. With the exception of the location.reload() line which I commented out, which did not break the tests, although this test runner is a bit different as its in a plunkr and that won't always be the case. You really should not be calling that in tests.

Comment: I did at first... then for a reason, when I tried to inject $location it gave me an error.

Either way that's not it, Even if I comment it nothing happens and I do not get the desired console.logs.

If that was the case, at least I would have seen a rapid refresh...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the error you got when you injected $location? location.reload() I am fairly sure will break jasmine tests. I understand that you commented it out, but bear that in mind.

Comment: the $location injection gave me "undefined is not a function" error. for some unknown reason.

I have no flush anywhere else in the code.

Comment: The fact that you test ran smoothly with the same code seems to prove that my code is built well at least.

Now I know I should look elsewhere.

Comment: Ok look the issue was my `angular-mock.js`  version...

You helped me find it with your answer so I mark you.